# rails render helper to return a p tag with '\n' as new line

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

I am getting this string with the '\n' inside and I would like to display a new line where is has the '\n' rather than displaying the raw strings

inside the fruits.description

```
fruits.description: 'This is an red apple \n It is also very sweet'
```

my render helper method

```
def get_description(fruits)
  if fruits.type == 'apple'
    haml_tag 'p', fruits.description, {id: fruits.id}
  end
end
```

I want the strings to display so that is like this

```
This is an red apple
It is also very sweet
```

Answer (score 10):

Try [`simple_format`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format), which will add the `<p>` tag as well as translate `\n` to `<br>` etc.

Specifically:

> Two or more consecutive newlines(\n\n) are considered as a paragraph and wrapped in `<p>` tags. One newline (\n) is considered as a linebreak and a `<br />` tag is appended.

Comment: I think you'll also have to use double quotes, not single quotes, right?

Comment: @Thilo I'm pretty sure quotes don't enter into it. The "code" he's posted with single quotes isn't actually code at all. I'm assuming that the `fruits.description: ...` line is simply him telling us what the string is, and that he's used single quotes where the real string is coming from a database and contains a literal newline.